# How to update variable values in html file for sending email in github actions?

Tags: html, variables, github, github-actions

I am trying to use the action from marketplace at this [link](https://github.com/juanformoso/action-send-mail).

It worked and the email is sent, but the variables are not expanded inside it.

The code snippet:

```
  - name: Send Build Email
    # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
    # uses: juanformoso/action-send-mail@523ea7dd83e339d3c64fc4fdc2da0efc9014ea03
    uses: juanformoso/action-send-mail@1
    with:
      # SMTP server address
      server_address: smtp.sendgrid.net
      # SMTP server port
      server_port: 587
      # Authenticate as this user to SMTP server
      username: apikey
      # Authenticate with this password to SMTP server
      password: ${{secrets.MAIL_PASSWORD}}
      # Subject of mail message
      subject: ${{ github.workflow }} - Build Successful, GitHub_Build:${{ env.git_commit_count }} GitHubWorkflow_Build:${{ github.run_number }}
      # Body of mail message (might be a filename prefixed with file:// to read from)
      body: "file://installs_repo/Projectwise ISM files/${{ env.Version }}/mart_installs_email.html"
      # Recipients mail addresses (separated with comma)
      to: myemail@company.com
      # Email address of the sender
      from: myemail@company.com
      # Content-Type HTTP header (text/html or text/plain)
      content_type: text/html
      # Convert body from Markdown to HTML (set content_type input as text/html too)
      convert_markdown: true
```

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>${{ github.workflow }} - Successful</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>GitHub Repository</td>
    <td>${{github.repository}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Github Actions Build Number</td>
    <td>${{ github.run_number }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GitHub Branch Name</td>
    <td>${{ github.ref_name }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit Message</td>
    <td>${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit Count or Build Number</td>
    <td>${{ env.git_commit_count }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daily Builds</td>
    <td>${{ secrets.DAILY_BUILDS_URL }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the email I am getting as like this.

[image: values not expanded]

How to set the values to expand, even I set the convert_markdown to true but still same issue.

I am trying to implement that using sed command in the cmd shell, as below.

```
  - name: Update HTML file values
    shell: cmd
    run: |
      set html=".\\installs_repo\\Projectwise ISM files\\${{ env.Version }}\\mart_installs_email.html"
      copy /Y ".\\installs_repo\\Projectwise ISM files\\${{ env.Version }}\\mart_installs_email.template" %html%
      sed -i "s/VAR_REPO/${{github.repository}}/g" %html%
      sed -i "s/VAR_RUNNER/${{ github.run_number }}/g" %html%
      sed -i "s/VAR_REF/${{ github.ref_name }}/g" %html%
      sed -i "s/VAR_COMMIT/${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}/g" %html%
      sed -i "s/VAR_COMMIT_COUNT/${{ env.git_commit_count }}/g" %html%
      sed -i "s/VAR_URL/${{ secrets.DAILY_BUILDS_URL }}/g" %html%
```

my html file entries changed now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>${{ github.workflow }} - Successful</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>GitHub Repository</td>
    <td>VAR_REPO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Github Actions Build Number</td>
    <td>VAR_RUNNER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GitHub Branch Name</td>
    <td>VAR_REF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit Message</td>
    <td>VAR_COMMIT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit Count or Build Number</td>
    <td>VAR_COMMIT_COUNT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Daily Builds</td>
    <td><a href="VAR_URL">OneDrive Link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But, getting errors as in screenshot.

[image: sed error]

Comment: GitHub Actions is only going to interpolate values into your actual workflow config, not any random file.

Comment: It doesn't mean my question is to be unliked or mark as not useful. Please let me know if you have any workaround

Comment: The "workaround" is use something that _will_ - in the language of your choice, find something that can generate the HTML from a template and some input data.

Comment: This is an action in marketplace, which I provided the link also in the question. Where they have  convert_markdown option, what is that for?

Comment: It says _in the config you show_ what it's for.

Comment: can you check once the above steps I tried

Comment: What do you mean _"check once"_? It's not at all clear why you think this is functionality that's even supported by the action you're using (or particularly why you think `convert_markdown` would help when you _don't have markdown_).

Comment: Please refresh the page and see the content I added

Comment: THank you , I am able to fix the sed part, by replacing the / with |

Comment: There is an issue now, I am replacing the commit message as a variable in the html file using sed. Somehow when there is * in the commit message, the sed commadn is failing

sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unterminated `s' command
'*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.